# How do I trim text/video in smaller increments? (for Kinetic Type Video)

Tags: video, video-editor, final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro

I want to trim a basic title element so it matches an audio file I have.

I want to drag the start of the title element to a marker on the timeline.

I can't do this because final cut keeps truncating the trim function. [image]

How do I raise the resolution that I can trim at?

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is normal because a title element is bound to the **video** frame rate. All visual elements must start/end in "between" frames. In your example GIF you zoomed enough in and even can see the markers. Note the line just below the timecode.

The reason sound is not bound to this is because sound has a much greater Samplerate. If you think of Samplerate and Framerate as Data points over time then you understand video has commonly 24 or 25 (higher fps becomes more common) data points in a second, sound usually has 48000 data points per second.

Have your title element start at a frame what feels the best.

Comment: I feel like I need more accuracy in terms of lining the text up with the audio to make the video look compelling. Will using a program such as After effects allow me to do this?

Comment: As far as I know in all NLEs it would be the same. Visual elements are restricted to the video frame rate. IMHO nobody will see the difference if the text starts couple subframes earlier or later. Remember you zoomed in so far that you have almost 1 frame shown in the entire timeline and you have 25 of them I a second. Most people can’t even see when the sound is off sync by a frame or two. I don’t think It gains you any more accuracy.

Comment: It is possible I have inadvertently changed some setting in final cut pro which lowers the resolution of the timeline?

Comment: Not necessarily, you always can zoom into subframe level. Just zoom out until you see some clips next to each other. Then adjust the text to the sound. One frame won’t make a difference.